# atom-ui and seti-ui not working

Tags: user-interface, treeview, atom-editor

I wish to ask some of the Atom users here.

I'm having trouble with my UI. Suddenly, it stopped displaying right on my tree view. I did not change any settings or whatever. It just went like this after waking my laptop up from sleep. I've tried looking for solutions in the Atom forum but it seems like I have an unusual problem.

Here's the screenshot of my atom tree view:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Atom` was a big program I would take time to look into any settings or shortcuts that may have changed the settings.

However with this program it is TINY. I would recommend just reinstalling it. If you have a bunch of plugins its a pain... But you may end up spending more time trying to solve the problem than just reinstalling it!

Good luck!

Comment: Actually, I just did. Haha. Thanks for taking the time to answer though! I'll be more mindful before posting a question next time. :)

Comment: Awesome! I see that you accepted my answer! Thank, and one more thing. If you think my  answer was a quality answer please consider pushing the up arrow next to my answer. This gives me more reputation on the site. Please consider carefully and only do it if you think I deserve it! @LeoFrancisLallana Thanks!